# BMW 530i Navigation software

Tags: bmw, navigation

My friend has bought a BMW 530i from 2004, manufactured in Germany. The original navigation system installation disk is broken. I wounder if it can be downloaded, burnt to a cd/dvd and installed into the car. He lives in Lebanon, middle east, so the maps has to be for that area.

If there's other navigation software, provided by a third party that can work on his car, it's alright. And if the firmware has to be upgraded for the CD to work, it's fine but please provide a link for the new firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BMW service centre will be able to connect and download any software required via its internet access to BMW Germany. Must be a genuine **BMW facility** though.

Comment: ok I will tell him to do so, can't it be found online because i see some stuff here https://kickass.so/usearch/bmw%20navigation i dont know if they are legit or not but anyway wont work on the car, he doesnt need a map of europe :)